# I am coding a calculator and need help allowing user inputs to be floats

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

Okay, this is my code, it is in python 3.4.3 and I do not know how I would go about allowing user inputs to be floats. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
It is a calculator and works perfectly but it does not allow user inputs to be floats(have decimal places) and a lot of calculations take place with inputs of decimal numbers so it kinda needs it. Thanks if you take the time to read that!

```
import time

def cls(): print ("\n"*100)
def add():
cls()

print("you have selected addition")

a = input("Enter your first number: ")
while a.isdigit() == False:
    print("Enter a numerical interger")
    a = input("Enter your first number: ")
if a.isdigit() == True:
    a = int(a)
b = input("Enter your second number: ")
while b.isdigit() == False:
    print("Enter a numberical interger")
    b = input ("enter your second number: ")
if b.isdigit() == True:
    b = int(b)
print ("\n")
print ("ANSWER:",a,"+",b,"=",a+b)
print ("\n")

def sub():
    cls()
    print("you have selected subtraction")
    a = input("Enter your first number: ")
    while a.isdigit() == False:
        print("Enter a numerical interger")
        a = input("Enter your first number: ")
    if a.isdigit() == True:
        a = int(a)
    b = input("Enter your second number: ")
    while b.isdigit() == False:
    print("enter a numerical interger")
    b = input("Enter your second number: ")
    if b.isdigit() == True:
    b = int(b)
    print("\n")
    print ("ANSWER:",a,"-",b,"=",a-b)
    print("\n")
def multi():
    cls()
    print ("you have selected multiplication")
    a = input("Enter your first number: ")
    while a.isdigit() == False:
        print("Enter a numerical interger")
        a = input("Enter your first number: ")
    if a.isdigit() == True:
        a = int(a)
    b = input("Enter your second number: ")
    while b.isdigit() == False:
        print("enter a numerical interger")
        b = input("Enter your second number: ")
    if b.isdigit() == True:
        b = int(b)
    print("\n")
    print("ANSWER:",a,"*",b,"=",a*b)
    print("\n")
def divide():
    cls()
    print ("you have selected division")
    a = input("Enter your first number: ")
    while a.isdigit() == False:
        print("Enter a numerical interger")
        a = input("Enter your first number: ")
    if a.isdigit() == True:
        a = int(a)
    b = input("Enter your second number: ")
    while b.isdigit() == False:
        print("enter a numerical interger")
        b = input("Enter your second number: ")
    if b.isdigit() == True:
        b = int(b)
    c = (a/b)
    if a%b ==0 :
        print("\n")
        print ("ANSWER:",a,"/",b,"=",int(c))
        print("\n")
    else :
        print("\n")
        print ("ANSWER:",a,"/",b,"=",float(c))
        print("\n")

def indice():
    cls()
    print ("you have selected indice multiplication")
    a = input("Enter your first number: ")
    while a.isdigit() == False:
        print("Enter a numerical interger")
        a = input("Enter your first number: ")
    while (int(a)) >=1000000000000:
        print("value too high, enter a lower value")
        time.sleep(1)
        a = input("Enter your first number: ")
    if a.isdigit() == True:
        a = int(a)
    b = input("Enter your second number: ")
    while b.isdigit() == False:
        print("enter a numerical interger")
        b = input("Enter your second number: ")
    while (int(b)) >=1000:
        print("value too high, enter a lower value")
        time.sleep(1)
        b = input("Enter your second number: ")  
    if b.isdigit() == True:
        b = int(b)
    print("\n")
    print("ANSWER:",a,"To the power of",b,"=",a**b)
    print("\n")

def Tconv():
    cls()
    print("You have selected unit conversion")
    print("\n")
    print("Enter 1 for conversion from celcius")
    print("Enter 2 for conversion from kelvin")
    print("\n")
    a = input("Enter your choice: ")
    if a == "1":
        cls()
        Tcelc()
    elif a == "2":
        cls()
        Tkelv()
    else:
        print("Not a valid entry, try again")
        time.sleep(1)
        cls()
        Tconv()

def Tcelc():
    print("You have selected conversion from celcius")
    print("\n")
    a = input("Enter your celcius value: ")
    if a.isdigit() == False:
        print("Not a valid entry")
        time.sleep(1)
        cls()
        Tcelc()
    elif a.isdigit() == True:
        print("\n")
        print("AWNSER = ",(int(a))+273,"Kelvin")
        print("\n")

def Tkelv():
    print("You have selected conversion from kelvin")
    print("\n")
    a = input("Enter your kelvin value: ")
    if a.isdigit() == False:
        print("Not a valid entry")
        time.sleep(1)
        Tkelv()
    elif a.isdigit() == True:
        print("ANSWER = ",(int(a))-273,"Celcius")
        print("\n")

def OpEx():
        cls()
        print("what operation would you like to preform?")
        print("\n")
        print("Enter 1 for addition")
        print("Enter 2 for subtraction")
        print("Enter 3 for multliplication")
        print("Enter 4 for division")
        print("Enter 5 for indice multiplication")
        print("Enter 6 for unit conversion")
        print("\n")
        print("Or type 'close' to exit the program")
        print("\n")
        task = input("enter your choice: ")
        print("\n")
        if task == "1":
            add()
            menu()
        elif task == "2":
            sub()
            menu()
        elif task == "3":
            multi()
            menu()
        elif task == "4":
            divide()
            menu()
        elif task == "5":
            indice()
            menu()
        elif task == "6":
            Tconv()
            menu()
        elif task == "close":
            exit()
        else:
            print ("not a valid entry")
            time.sleep(2)
            OpEx()
def menu():
    Q1 = input("Type 'yes' to preform a calculation type 'no' to exit: ")
    if Q1 == "yes":
        OpEx()
    if Q1 == "no":
        print("sorry I could not be of futher service")
        time.sleep(1)
        exit()
    else:
        print("\n")
        print("Not a valid entry, try again")
        print("\n")
        time.sleep(1)
        cls()
        menu()
cls()
menu()
```

Comment: This doesn't address your problem, but it's more idiomatic to do `if b.isdigit():` and `if not b.isdigit():` instead of `if b.isdigit() == True:` and `if b.isdigit() == False:`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand?

Comment: `b.isdigit()` is already a Boolean expression. There's no need to compare it to `True`  or `False`.

Answer (score 1):

You're converting user input to integers, which don't handle floating point all that well. Try converting to `float` instead, e.g.:

```
a = float(a)
```

Comment: Okay will do, but the problem still remains, as while a.isdigit() == False: is still satisfied when a float is inputted from the user, so you get the "Enter a numerical interger" message and the float input is never computed!

Comment: You could skip that check and handle the ValueError exception that will be raised if you have an invalid float value.

Comment: Took me a long while to fix the programme, but it worked so thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I would be cautious taking the input as a float because python and many other languages floats are not represented as they may seem. I would recommend pulling the input as a string and then casting it later.

Comment: What does this even mean? It doesn't make any sense - "*floats are not represented as they may seem*."

Comment: for instance in python it can appear that you have 10.0083 == 10.0083 returning false when in reality there are a ton of more zeros trailing those numbers with garbage after them.  So say you try incrementing a float with a loop such as x = .0000056 while x < 10: x = x + .0000001, your loop can possibly never break